# AutoMapper Conditional Mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

If ready to start is false, then I need to set ActualStartDate to default. Or maybe I will make a nullable instead.

The RequestDates collection will always have just 1 record.

```
    public class EngagementDto
    {
        #region Public Properties

        public bool ReadyToStart { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<RequestDateDto> RequestDates { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class RequestDateDto
    {
        #region Public Properties

        public DateTime ActualStartDate { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

Not sure If I'm going about this correctly...but this is what I have so far.

```
            CreateMap<EngagementDto, RequestDateDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ActualStartDate, opt =>
                {
                    opt.Condition((src, dest) => !src.ReadyToStart);
                    opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i think it's can be working!

```
 CreateMap<EngagementDto, RequestDateDto>()
                ForMember(dest => dest.RequestDates, 
                   opt => opt.MapFrom
                   (src => dest.ReadyToStart ? "your default value" : src.ActualStartDate));
```

way number two

change your model like this

```
public IEnumerable<RequestDateDto> RequestDates { get; set; } = null
```

and then

```
CreateMap<EngagementDto,RequestDateDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.RequestDates, opt => {
        opt.PreCondition(src => (src.ReadyToStart));
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.ActualStartDate);
```

Comment: I don't have access to dest in this part...
src => dest.ReadyToStart

Comment: try this, I added other way